# VSCode/dotnet CLI: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, dotnet-cli

VSCode Version:1.61.2
dotnet CLI Version:2.1.500

I'm run:

```
dotnet new webapi -n MY_APP_NAME
dotnet build
dotnet run
```

Output:

```
...
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
...
```

When I browse to:`http://localhost:5000` I get:

[image: Chrome ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR Error]

How do I solve this?

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your app is setup with => app.UseHttpsRedirection();

If thats the case you should setup the dev-certs.

Maybe this article can help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#trust-the-aspnet-core-https-development-certificate-on-windows-and-macos